# Can I create a font based on the Testarossa badge font?

Tags: copyright

The testarossa badge is a beautiful work of art and its a shame that no one has made a font based on it.

I am going to guess, someone may have, but Ferarri shut them down - as they are known to do, as they agressively like to to protect their brand.

However, I imagine creating a font that is similar to it in style would not constitute copyright, otherwise Arial wouldn't exist.

[image]

I noticed the Boohoo logo has a very similar font style to it, without the inline.

[image]

My question is then, could I create a font based on the testarotta logo, so it looks similar?

Comment: To me the fonts are totally different. boohoo o's are square. The distance between the top of the lower letters (o, esarossa) and the higher letters (b, t) is totally different.

Comment: Ferrari's "O" is square too.  And both only include a small handful of letters out of 26, so if Ferrari hasn't sued BooHoo yet I think you'd be safe making an original, but stylistically similar font including all 26 letters that wouldn't garner unwanted attention.  There are LOTS of very similar looking fonts out there, I wouldn't think twice unless you are planning to compete in the same sports car market, using your mispelled "testarotta" as a car name in a way that mimics theirs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be copyright infringement, depends on how you do it. The design of a typeface is not protected as a work of art under US copyright law ([Eltra v. Ringer](https://casetext.com/case/eltra-corp-v-ringer)), but the digital files that typically constitute the realization of a font / typeface is protected  by copyright. You may carefully recreate the artistic design of a typeface, if you can, and this is not infringement. But if you obtain a font file and manipulate it, that would be copyright infringement.

However... [in some countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property_protection_of_typefaces), typeface design is protected (e.g. Germany. That article doesn't say what the status of typeface design copyright is in Italy, and [this version of the Italian copyright law](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/it/it211en.pdf) doesn't seem to contain anything corresponding to typeface design protection, but I suggest hiring a lawyer that does Italian copyright law first.

Comment: In this particular case, there is no typeface for this logo. It does not exist. So the resulting one I would create would be made from scratch. My changes to the original would include a larger radius on the corners, some letters will be different and the inline a different thickness.

Comment: Why would you want to check with an Italian lawyer, or even a German? Unless you're of course Italian or German, or selling to those countries.

Comment: I'm assuming that Ferrari is based in Italy and would hold the copyright, if any. This is like me suing a German person in US courts for infringement that took place elsewhere: the US is a convenient forum. If it were about typeface design, I wouldn't sue in US courts. I wouldn't sue in German courts *unless* they have jurisdiction, which we can't judge from the proposed scenario.